# Choosing initial values for variables and parameters for optimizers in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How do people typically choose initial values for their variables and parameters? Do we just tinker till it works?

I was following the Getting Started tutorial for tensorflow, and was able to train the linear model in it. However, I noticed that the starting values for the variables W, b were reasonably close to the ground truth.

When I change the data to make the ground truth values much further away, the gradient descent optimizer gives me NaN values for W, b.

However, in general, I don't think it would be reasonable to be able to guess the initial values of the variables in the model. Seems like I should be able to choose any arbitrary starting point and get to where I want.

I was thinking my choice in my parameters might be bad. However, I am not sure in what way to adjust this. The default was 0.01, I've tried values from 0.001 to 100.

Would there be a discussion of optimization parameter choices and initial values for model variables in a general machine learning book? Really I am just looking for resources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the famous initializers for Convolutional Neural Networks:

**Glorot Normal**: Also called Xavier. Normal distribution centered on 0 with stddev = sqrt(2 / (fan_in + fan_out)) where fan_in is the number of input units in the weight tensor and fan_out is the number of output units in the weight tensor.

http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

**Lecun Uniform**: Uniform distribution within [-limit, limit] where limit is sqrt(3 / fan_in) where  fan_in is the number of input units in the weight tensor.

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf

**He Normal**:
Truncated normal distribution centered on 0 with stddev = sqrt(2 / fan_in) where  fan_in is the number of input units in the weight tensor.

http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852

Along with these initializers, one have to search for learning rate, momentum and other hyperparameters.